# Python Pandas out of bounds datetime timestamp error for long dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have a data frame `df` with shape `(500000,70)` and several columns including invalid dates like `4000-01-01 00:00:00`. In a smaller version of this data frame I tried

```
df["date"] = df["date"].astype(str)
df["date"] = df["date"].replace('4000-01-01 00:00:00', pd.NaT)
```

which worked fine. Also the version

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"].replace("4000-01-01 00:00:00",pd.NaT))
```

worked. For the long data frame version I receive the following error

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 4000-01-01 00:00:00
```

Any suggestions how to solve this problem in an elegant way or what the problem might be?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If add parameter `errors='coerce'` to [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) function it return `NaT` for all not parseable datetimes:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], errors='coerce')
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because:

```
In [332]: pd.Timestamp.max
Out[332]: Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807')
```

The upper limit of the date is this. And your value is out of the range, hence OutOfBoundsError.